# How to calculate and output multiple results according to one equation in python?

Tags: python

So I know how to define the function, but I don't know how to output two results where `t=0` and `t=1`.

[image: Output for g(0) and g(1)]

Here is my code:

```
from math import exp
from math import pi
from math import sin


def g(t):
    a = exp(-t)
    b = sin(pi*t)
    g = a*b
    return g

t=0
print(g)
```

Comment: You can't just print `g`! As you said, you want to print `g(0)` and `g(1)`. The computer doesn't know this unless you tell it.

Comment: Why do you use three separate imports? You can just use  `from math import exp, pi, sin`.

Answer (score 2):

## Call your function

`g` is a function. `print(g)` literally prints the function object. `print(g(t))` prints the function `g` evaluated at `t`. So, you want this after the definition of `g`:

```
print(g(0)) # Print g evaluated at t=0
print(g(1)) # Print g evaluated at t=1
```

## Don't reuse variable names

Don't do `g = a * b`. Rename it something like `h`. By doing that, you're redefining `g` to mean something different in the local scope which can get confusing. Functions are objects too!

## Don't use too many intermediate variables

For your `g` function, you use a total of 3 intermediate variables. Normally, having intermediate variables is useful for readability. Here, it's not necessary:

```
def g(t):
    return exp(-t) * sin(pi * t)
```

(This makes it resemble the task more anyway...)

Comment: @user8673326: In addition to HyperNeutrino's note on the assignment `g = a * b`, you probably just wants to use `return a * b` instead of ever assigning that value a name at all.

Comment: @ZachGates That's true; I'd like to rewrite the whole `g` function anyway :P I'll add that in, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your function more times in the future, you could put your arguments into a list and do this:

```
for arg in [0, 1]:
    print(g(arg))
```

Also, you can return the value directly without re-assigning to `g`:

```
def g(t):
    a = exp(-t)
    b = sin(pi*t)
    return a*b
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses tuples to return multiple values from a function:

```
def two_vals(): 
   return 11,22

>>> two_vals()
(11, 22)
```

You can use tuple expansion to assign multiple values to multiple named values:

```
>>> g1, g2=two_vals()
>>> g1
11
>>> g2
22
```

So. Rewrite your function so that it calculates both values. Return both (as a list, tuple, dict, whatever data structure) and you have your two values to print.

To fulfill this assignment however, you could just call `g` twice and place into a string to print:

```
def g(t):
    a = exp(-t)
    b = sin(pi*t)
    g = a*b
    return g

def both_g_str():
    return "g(0): {}, g(1): {}".format(g(0), g(1))
```